# jQuery: get the name of the selected image in drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to get the name of the image selected in a drag and drop function using jquery.

For this I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({

        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stack: '.drag',
        revert: "invalid"


    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({



                    drop: function (e, ui) {

                    var srcc=$("#droppable").find('img').attr('src');
                    alert(srcc);    




                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                        ui.helper.remove();




                    x.draggable({

                        //helper: 'original',
                        containment: '#droppable',
                        tolerance: 'fit',
                        stack: '.drag'



                    });

                    x.resizable({

                      animate: true,
                      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                      handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"

                    });
                    x.appendTo('#droppable');

                }

                }

            });

});
```

Please take a note of this line:

```
            var srcc=$("#droppable").find('img').attr('src');
            alert(srcc);
```

the problem is that on drop, I cannot get the name of the selected image/div!

P.S. by name of the image, I mean the actual URL of the image :

example: `images/image_name.jpg`

I have created a jsfiddle to explain the issue further.

please drag and drop the images in teh box bellow them and take a note of the `alert();` message.

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7s1w4jgq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **$("#droppable")** use **ui.draggable**

```
var srcc=ui.draggable.find('img').attr('src');
alert(srcc);
```

it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get it from ui.helper in your case because you are using `helper: 'clone'`:

```
var srcc = ui.helper.find("img").attr("src")
alert(srcc);
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could just use:

```
e.srcElement.currentSrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Call ui.draggable as the selector instead of your class name

```
var srcc = $(ui.draggable).find('img').attr('src');
    alert(srcc);
```

The problem is that you are not binding the element to the event.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s1w4jgq/6/)